# Android Facebook API - StringBuilder returns NULL

Tags: android, facebook, nullpointerexception

I'm working through the Android Facebook tutorial here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/androidsdk/3.0/fetch-user-data/

In this chunk of code:

```
private String buildUserInfoDisplay(GraphUser user) {

        StringBuilder userInfo = new StringBuilder("");
        Log.d("Graphuser:user",user.toString());
        Log.d("StringBuilder:userInfo",userInfo.toString());
        // Example: typed access (name)
        // - no special permissions required
        Log.d("Name: ",String.format("Name: %s\n\n", user.getName()));

        userInfo.append(String.format("Name: %s\n\n", user.getName()));

        // Example: typed access (birthday)
        // - requires user_birthday permission
        //userInfo.append(String.format("Birthday: %s\n\n", user.getBirthday()));

        // Example: partially typed access, to location field,
        // name key (location)
        // - requires user_location permission
        //userInfo.append(String.format("Location: %s\n\n", user.getLocation().getProperty("name")));

        // Example: access via property name (locale)
        // - no special permissions required
        userInfo.append(String.format("Locale: %s\n\n", user.getProperty("locale")));

     // Get a list of languages from an interface that
     // extends the GraphUser interface and that returns
     // a GraphObject list of MyGraphLanguage objects.
     GraphObjectList<MyGraphLanguage> languages = (user.cast(MyGraphUser.class)).getLanguages();
     Log.d("Languages",languages.toString());
     if (languages.size() > 0) {
         ArrayList<String> languageNames = new ArrayList<String> ();
         // Iterate through the list of languages
         for (MyGraphLanguage language : languages) {
             // Add the language name to a list. Use the name
             // getter method to get access to the name field.
             languageNames.add(language.getName());
         }                      

         //userInfo.append(String.format("Languages: %s\n\n", languageNames.toString()));
     }

        return userInfo.toString();
    }
```

The **userInfo.append()** function results in a null pointer exception.
Has anyone run into this before? I have checked that I have the same code as what is in the tutorial.

/* Update - Append Logcat */

```
03-16 17:59:18.154: W/dalvikvm(1189): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at net.myname.myapp.MainFragment.buildUserInfoDisplay(MainFragment.java:84)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at net.myname.myapp.MainFragment.access$2(MainFragment.java:56)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at net.myname.myapp.MainFragment$2.onCompleted(MainFragment.java:125)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at com.facebook.Request$1.onCompleted(Request.java:264)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at com.facebook.Request$4.run(Request.java:1240)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
03-16 17:59:18.204: E/AndroidRuntime(1189):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-16 17:59:18.354: D/dalvikvm(1189): GC_CONCURRENT freed 423K, 6% free 8428K/8903K, paused 107ms+76ms, total 316ms
```

Comment: Which userInfo.append? I'd say user.getProperty("locale") here might return null for some reason. I haven't tried it though. I was just having a quick glance at this question :)

Comment: Add here your logcat.

Comment: @Sajmon - Added logcat

Comment: @Kap - It's any userInfo.append. If I comment out the first, the next one fails.

Comment: Mmm...smells like concurrency issue...it can't fail like that...

Comment: @Kap - I'm fairly new to network programming with Android, any tips on how I can debug this issue?

Comment: Did you just copy the example or changed something? It is not easy to tell like this...I am not even sure that it's related to concurrency. As quick test, you could try to synchronize buildUserInfoDisplay to make sure it is not because of multiple thread access.
EDIT: or use StringBuffer which is thread safe...

Comment: @Kap - Hey, good call! I put a statement that was failing in a synchronize block and it fixed it. Feel free to add the answer and I'll mark it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code fails when the user has not provided that information on facebook. Wrap the code with try and catch for the java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something related to the thread safety of your `buildUserInfoDisplay`, because StringBuilder is not supposed to fail like that. Probably there are different threads accessing the function at the same time and this is causing the NPE (internal to StringBuilder?).

Try to synchronize the method or use `StringBuffer` instead of `StringBuilder`, which is thread-safe.

Ps.: wow, it's like writing for glory :)

Comment: Hey sorry Kap, I actually unknowingly commented out the offending lines of code as I was testing your suggestion, so I jumped the gun when I confirmed your solution.